# How to Upload,display and save image in a database table using jQuery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

How to upload , display and save image in a database. jQuery JavaScript using API calls .

I have four fields in db 
File I'd
Filename
Filesize
Filepath

Comment: what have you tried so far? maybe you should take a look into dropzone, its pretty easy with it and you will find examples on how to save it.. just to know, you dont save the file in your database, you save it in your filesystem and have the path in your database..

Comment: Yes I have to save the path in db and if you know how to do it  so please tell  me how can I do this ?

Comment: as i wrote, try to do it with: http://www.dropzonejs.com/ .. in my opionion there is no need to code something new (especially if you have no clue how) if there are options where you dont need to do all by yourself.. here fore example is one tutorial: https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-file-upload-form-using-dropzonejs-and-php and there are many out there..

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any mention of server side languages such as PHP listed here, but you need some sort of server side implementation to upload an image and deal with the database.

Ill help you go in the right direction so you know what to look up and look for.

**Uploading an image**
To upload an image you would conventionally use a form element with an `input` of type `file`. The form action would be your php upload script. The upload script can be complex, but they tend to be the same once you get the hang of it. Take a look at this page: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. It has a full php upload script.

**Store in database**
To 'store' the image in the database you just need to save the path to the image. This means you will need to setup your SQL database, and a table. Then use PHP's SQL database functions to `INSERT` the link into the table, along with your other data.

**Display the image**
To display the image you will need to use a php script to gain access to the database, and then use a specific ID to get the image path out of the table and output it to the page.

**Conclusion**
Uploading files is an age old problem, and is tough until you've done it a few times. In the comments i saw mention of dropzone.js, which is really great for handling the uploading of multiple images but it does not actually do the uploading, you still need to write some php. Dropzone is purely a front end tool.

Hope that helps you move in the right direction!